# $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ is an open subset of $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ but not of $[0,1]^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm new to Real analysis and reading the chapter on metric spaces in the book 'Real Analysis
with Economic Applications'. It is stated in the book that $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ is an open subset of $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ but not of $[0,1]^2$. Is the singleton $\{0\}$ open in itself?

Comment: Welcome on mathstackexchange. You will get better responses if you show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes every space is open itself.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thanks. What confused me is the concept of subspace topology which states singleton is closed under 'usual topolgy'. Could you please explain how is that case different from my question?

Comment: @pb10 I will write an answer.

Comment: It depends on "usual topology" of what. If you are considering the usual topology of the reals (or of the plane) then every singleton is closed. If you are considering a singleton in the (only possible topology) of itself, then it is both open and closed. You might have been confused by the repetition of "singletons are closed" taken out of context (and also because sets that are closed and open simultaneously also may be confusing at first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove the following:

If $A$ is open in $X$ and $B$ is open in $Y$, then $A \times B$ is open in $X \times Y$.

It follows that $(0,1)\times \{0\}$ is open in $[0,1]\times \{0\}$.

To see that this set is not open in $[0,1]^2$, note that any open ball inside $[0,1]^2$
centered at $(1/2,0)$ has points that are not in $[0,1]\times \{0\}.$